# AWS PartitionsLoader

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an application sending files to S3 - after a recent upgrade to the latest version of the AWS SDK I am getting the following when trying to upload a file to S3. I have tried searching for similar issues but to no avail and Amazon themselves have no ideas either.

```
Transfer failed for .... with exception com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.enable([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser$Feature;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper; current exception count 1
09 Sep 2016 15:48:48,176 ERROR [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] Transfer failed for ... with exception com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.partitions.PartitionsLoader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.  Turned out that my dependency was out of date: jackson-databind.  Update to 2.6.6 or later.